# C++ program to swap links of a Linked List

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

In this code I tried to swap links in a linked list instead of swapping data.Please Review my code.

```
#include <iostream>

    template<class T>
    class LinkedList
    {
struct Node{
  T data;
  Node * next;
  Node(T val): data(val), next(nullptr){}
};

Node* head;

public:

  LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

  void insert(T val)
  {
    Node* node = new Node(val);
    Node* tmp  = head;

    if(tmp == nullptr)
    {
      head = node;
    }
    else
    {
      while(tmp->next != nullptr)
      {
        tmp = tmp->next;
      }
      tmp->next = node;
    }
  }

  void swapLinks(T val1, T val2)
  {
    Node* prevNode1 = nullptr;
    Node* prevNode2 = nullptr;
    Node* nextNode1 = nullptr;
    Node* nextNode2 = nullptr;
    Node* node      = head;
    Node* node1     = search(val1);
    Node* node2     = search(val2);

    while(node->next != node1)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }
    if(node->next == node1)
    {
      prevNode1 = node;
      nextNode1 = node1->next;
    }

    node = head;

    while(node-> next != node2)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }
    if(node->next == node2)
    {
      prevNode2 = node;
      nextNode2 = node2->next;
    }

    prevNode1->next = node2;
    Node* tmp       = node2->next;
    node2->next     = node1->next;
    prevNode2->next = node1;
    node1->next     = tmp;
  }

  friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, LinkedList<T>& ll)
  {
    ll.display(os);
    return os;
  }

private:

  struct Node *search(T val)
  {
    Node* node = head;
    while(node != nullptr)
    {
      if(node->data == val)
      {
        return node;
      }
      node = node->next;
    }
    std::cerr << "No such element in the List \n";
    return nullptr;
  }

  void display(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const
  {
    Node* node = head;
    while(node != nullptr)
    {
      out << node->data <<" ";
      node = node->next;
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  LinkedList<int> ll1;
  ll1.insert(10);
  ll1.insert(15);
  ll1.insert(12);
  ll1.insert(13);
  ll1.insert(28);
  ll1.insert(14);
  ll1.insert(16);
  std::cout << "LinkedList1 : "<< ll1 <<"\n";
  ll1.swapLinks(12, 14);
  std::cout << ll1 <<"\n";


}
```

Is there any another solution or better solution? Please suggest.

Comment: Much easier to this if you have a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as long as 2 conditions are met.

1. val1 and val2 are in the list.
2. Neither are in the head node.

Otherwise you access stuff via null pointers:

```
  void swapLinks(T val1, T val2)
  {
    Node* prevNode1 = nullptr;
    Node* prevNode2 = nullptr;
    Node* nextNode1 = nullptr;
    Node* nextNode2 = nullptr;
    Node* node      = head;
    Node* node1     = search(val1);
    Node* node2     = search(val2);

    // This will not find values in the "head node"
    // If the value is in head the you will not find a previous node.
    // You need to take into account this special case at the bottom.
    while(node->next != node1)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }
    if(node->next == node1)
    {
      prevNode1 = node;
      nextNode1 = node1->next;
    }

    node = head;

    // This will not find values in the "head node"
    // If the value is in head the you will not find a previous node.
    // You need to take into account this special case at the bottom.
    while(node-> next != node2)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }
    if(node->next == node2)
    {
      prevNode2 = node;
      nextNode2 = node2->next;
    }

    // HERE YOU HAVE some issues.
    // prevNode1 or prevNode2 or node1 or node2 may be nullptr
    // If any of these values are null the code below will be UB.
    prevNode1->next = node2;
    Node* tmp       = node2->next;
    node2->next     = node1->next;
    prevNode2->next = node1;
    node1->next     = tmp;
  }
```